Spring Data JPA Specification - MSSQL - datediff
I am trying to mimick this MSSQL function in a Spring Data JPA v3.3.4 Specification, Hibernate v6.6.1.Final:
DATEDIFF(HOUR, entityB.createdDate, GETDATE()) BETWEEN 0 AND 1
return (root, query, criteriaBuilder) -> {

    Join<EntityA, EntityB> joinAB = (Join<EntityA, EntityB>) getOrCreateJoin(root, "fieldC");

    criteriaBuilder.between(
        criteriaBuilder.function(
            "DATEDIFF",
            Integer.class,
            criteriaBuilder.literal("HOUR"),
            joinAB.get("createdDate"), // Start date
            criteriaBuilder.function("GETDATE", LocalDateTime.class) // End date
       ),
       0, 1 // Range in hours
   )

The error i am getting is:
Caused by: org.hibernate.query.sqm.produce.function.FunctionArgumentException: Parameter 1 of function 'timestampdiff()' has type 'TEMPORAL_UNIT', but argument is of type 'java.lang.Object'

Seems like the error is coming from this argument:
criteriaBuilder.literal("HOUR")


Can you show the full stack trace?
